# How to implement different height for each tabview content

Tags: flutter, tabbar, tabview

I am learning flutter I am making a recipe app using API. I need to add a tab bar inside a ListView. But it only worked when I added tabview inside a sizedbox or container with height. But my problem is each content is different size. Some need a height of 1000, but some only need 500. How can I assign different heights according to the content?

```
ListView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    children: [
                      
                      
                      Text(
                        _response!.strMeal,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color(0xff042628),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DefaultTabController(
                        length: 2,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xffE7EAF2),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                              child: TabBar(
                                labelColor: Colors.white,
                                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: const Color(0xff042628),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                                tabs: const [
                                  Tab(
                                    text: 'Ingredients',
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    text: 'Instructions',
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 800, //i want to rid of this height
                              child: TabBarView(
                                children: [
                                  Text(_response!.strArea),
                                  Text(_response!.strInstructions),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Expanded` instead of using `Sizedbox`
hope it will work.

```
 Expanded(  //use expanded here
          child: TabBarView(
           children: [
               Text(_response!.strArea),
               Text(_response!.strInstructions),
                  ],
                    ),
                     ),
```

Comment: Expanded not working inside listview

Comment: ok, try to use colunm instead of using Listview, then inside TabBarView you can use listview for every tab